# How can I specify optional Query Parameters

Tags: java, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I defined query parameter in my contract. I need this parameter to be optional:

```
method 'GET'
    url($(regex(urlRegex))) {
        queryParameters {
            parameter 'fitler': $(stub(regex(filterRegex)))
        }
}
```

I want this contract to be suitable for the both URLs with filter like `/my/sample/url?fitler=some-filter-expression` and without the filter param like `/my/sample/url`.

How can I achieve this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you managed to achieve this? I'm dealing with the same problem right now

Comment: I have the same problem. What I found in my researches was that just create multiple contracts for presence or absence of that query param :|

Comment: spring cloud contract uses wiremock behind the scene, and it does not seem wiremock supports optional query parameter: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wiremock-user/WKMkb_LhJTU

Answer (score 1):

So far, this has no explicit way defined in WireMock spec. However, you have a workaround using regex, by specifying the URL using `urlPathPattern` property (in JSON stubbing). Refer to the example below.

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/myapp/users(\\?((a-zA-Z\\d\\_\\-)+\\=(a-zA-Z\\d\\_\\-)+)(\\&(a-zA-Z\\d\\_\\-)+\\=(a-zA-Z\\d\\_\\-)+)+)?"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
            "bodyFileName": "users.json",
            "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

Observe the optional portion at the end of the URL, which looks for the typical URL query structure. This, I have tried out in wiremock and it runs smoothly.